# How to find column name for invalid text representation 7 error invalid input syntax for integer in laravel?

Tags: laravel, postgresql

e.g., I have a table...

```
create table emp(  
  empno    integer,  
  ename    character varying(255),  
  job      character varying(255),  
  mgr      integer,  
  hiredate timestamp without time zone,  
  sal      double pricision,  
  comm     integer,  
  deptno   integer
)
```

When I try to insert the data...

```
insert into emp (empno,ename,job,mgr,hiredate,sal,comm,deptno) values (1,'abc','abc','e','2018-10-12 00:00:00',50.50,1,'f');
```

Then it's giving me an error of `invalid text representation 7 error invalid input syntax for integer` because I have inserted string value for `mgr` and `deptno` this can be found only by viewing the values, but PostgreSQL is not giving me the exact column name in which it has encounter such issue. Is there any way to get column name in the error message itself. Because when we have more than 50 to 60 columns, then it's challenging to find the column which has the issue.

Comment: why do you label this question in laravel

Comment: because I have used Laravel to insert the data. @MohdSamganKhan

Comment: can you show us that code? @Dhaval Purohit

Answer (score 7):

You don't have to find out which column is wrong because you should make sure your inputs are properly formatted BEFORE inserting in the database.

You are using Laravel, so you should make use of the great toolset it offers for validation: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation

For example in your case, you should validate `mgr` by using the following rule at the start of your controller:

```
$request->validate([
    'mgr' => 'number'
]);
```

This will throw an exception if the rule is not respected, and thus will fail when the user is trying to input data, not when your backend tries to insert the data in the DB.

Comment: ok thanks, I know that but what if I didn't put the validation. Without this can I achieve this?

Comment: Yes but you shouldn't

Comment: This answer does make a very valid point. While you could probably find a way to get the column name, I think you're focusing on the wrong aspect of the problem. If you have control over your code base, your main focus should be to make sure that user input is validated and sanitized properly before being passed along to the database. In that case such cryptic errors will occur far less for edge cases only and would be much less of a hassle to debug. I agree it would be cool to have a solution to this issue, but to me it seems a waste of time if it keeps you from continuing development.

Answer (score 2):

You can catch the sql query exception using class `\Illuminate\Database\QueryException` and can customize the sql exception as per your requirements.

```
try {
    // Add your insert query here.

} catch (\Illuminate\Database\QueryException $e) {

    // Here you can get the sql exception details.
    dd($e->getMessage(), $e->errorInfo); // print for the details info.

    // customzie you error

} catch (\Exception $e) {

    // for the other exception.
    dd($e->getMessage(), $e->errorInfo); // print for the details info.
}
```

You can also use the Laravel Exception Handling to customize the message at common place.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/errors

Comment: @DhavalPurohit does this help?

Comment: What's concern now? I think, it helps you to add fields in error message.

Comment: Please add more details where it's lacking so we can add/update solution as per that.

Comment: @VikasPathak just try to generate the exception as i shown in the question
you will get a whole message like `invalid text representation 7 error invalid input syntax for integer` but you will never get the column name either in the `$e->getMessage()` or `$e->errorInfo`

Comment: There would be some manual steps you'll have to include like, extract the "input text" from the error message and map with the `fields => values` array to get the desired field name.

Comment: yes that we can do if field have the values but suppose if it has the empty string that this will be difficult. whatever the main concern is that is postgresql is not giving such kind of functionality so what can we do. only way is to resolved the issue is validate the data before insert and use transaction if you are dealing with import/export from excel files that's it.